# Create intervals based on condition for annotate ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, intervals

I have a vector called `ranks` with values from -6 to 6 and I want to create intervals of number of values based on value intervals such as (2, Inf) [2, 1.25) etc that include the number of values in that interval, plus the ones in the previous interval. In other words, for interval of values (2, Inf) I want to obtain the number of values in this interval plus those in the previous one.

To do this I used a very primitive approach:

```
   xmin <- c(0, sum(ranks>2),
            sum(ranks>2) + sum(ranks>1.25),
            sum(ranks>2) + sum(ranks>1.25) + sum(ranks>0.75),
            sum(ranks>2) + sum(ranks>1.25) + sum(ranks>0.5) + sum(ranks>0.25)) 
   xmax <- c(c(sum(ranks>2),
            sum(ranks>2) + sum(ranks>1.25),
            sum(ranks>2) + sum(ranks>1.25) + sum(ranks>0.75),
            sum(ranks>2) + sum(ranks>1.25) + sum(ranks>0.5) + sum(ranks>0.25))-1,
            length(ranks))
```

Where xmin is the start of each interval and xmax the end of each interval. But I believe there is a much better straightforward way to do it.

Overall I'd like to find the values separating in this intervals: +Inf, 2, 1, 0.5, 0, -0.5, -1, -2, -Inf

PS: I'll be using these to annotate x axis in ggplot2 as shown below (see the color scale from red to blue, those are rectangles with specific x and y delimiters)
[image]

Comment: this question leaves me really confused... the annotation, do you mean you want to get the segments, or the color? I assume there might be a much more direct way to get either

Comment: This is to get the color by function annotate from ggplot2 that asks for the start and end of each rectangle.

Comment: It doesn't really matter of course, because you will probably be happy with the solution - but I feel that you might be overcomplicating things and that there might be a more direct way of what you want to achieve. The problem is that I still don't understand what you want to achieve :D

Comment: So do I, but I couldn't find any better way. Basically, I have 11k genes in a vector and each gene has a stat value. I want different box colors over the x axis depending on the stat value. The problem is that the function (annotate()) that allows me to do this, requires the x axis position and this is the number of the gene inside the 11k gene vector. Therefore I have to find the border genes, which is what I've asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 2, 5, 3) %>% 
  cut(c(0, 2, 4, 6)) %>% 
  table() %>%
  cumsum()
```

```
(0,2] (2,4] (4,6] 
    7    10    13
```

UPD: just noticed - you're arranging your intervals in reverse. I think the easiest way would be to convert the table to numeric and `rev`erse it before `cumsum`ing

Comment: Yes, but your code is perfect, with some arrangements (reverse basically) I can do what I want pretty easily, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I might still have misunderstood, but in the end it's just a matter of counting how many genes are in each interval, correct?

Basically you're re-inventing a stacked bar.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# random data
set.seed(1)
rank <- sample(-6:6, 11000, replace = T)
# vector of your cuts
my_cuts <- c(-Inf, -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, Inf)
## make a data frame and cut the ranks
genes <-  data.frame(rank)
genes$cuts <- cut(genes$rank, my_cuts)

## just use geom_bar
ggplot(genes) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = 1, fill = cuts)) +
  ## now you can simply use one of the scale functions
  scale_fill_brewer(palette =  "Reds")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I could reproduce it, but I'm struggling to add this as a layer to my previous set of ggplot layers. This is definitely more straight forward, tomorrow I'll try to get it. Anyway, I have another question, would it be possible with this approach to limit the bars y position, from -0.5 to 0, for example? Thank you very much!

Comment: @PauClavell if you mean the width of the bar - for sure. The bar centre is defined by your y (in my example 1), and the width by the width parameter. in your case, you would thus write  `geom_bar(aes(y = -.25, fill = cuts), width = .5)`